# (Re-)Parametrization of contour integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, parametrization

I am working with Marsdens/Hoffmanns book "Basic Complex Analysis" (3rd edition). They define the contour integral and show on page 99 that it if you integrate a function along a representation and along a reparametrization of a curve you will get the same answer for both integrals.

Then they state that this result justifies that you can parametrize a geometric curve and you will always get the set answer independent of the parametrization chosen. But thats not quite correct as the footnote explains and I understand the problem.

The footnote also says that if we ignore points where $\gamma'(t)=0$ we get reparametrizations but there is no explanation why. Do you have an idea why this is correct? (I figured out that if you can parametrize the curve by a parametrization that is injective and you have another one that's also injective than you can give a changing map between them and so one is a reparametrization of the other. Using this argument I would claim $\gamma'(t)$ has to be strictly postive or negative.)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try - really hard - to read your question as if you were not the author, and didn't know anything at all about what you were thinking of as you wrote it. Does it still seem understandable to you?

Comment: Sorry…I agree. Maybe in short: Can anybody tell me, why the footnote in the book is correct? I don’t see, why the condition $\gamma‘(t)\neq 0$ guarantees that two parametrizations are reparametrizations of each other.